# Pass Dynamic Selection for DropDownList ASP and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a Repeater that will post a User Name, their permission levels, and a remove button.
The permission level is suppose to sit in a drop down list. The default value is suppose to be what ever the user currently has.

IE

USER A, Guest

USER B, Group Member

USER C, Group Admin

Changing these will eventually fire a sql command to change them in the Database. But that isn't a problem, I know how to do that.

The values are coming from the repeater source.

ASP CODE:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="User_Repeater_Source" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:app_migrationConnectionString  %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Membership.*, Users.Email, Users.Last_Name + ', ' + Users.First_Name + ' (' + Membership.User_ID + ')' as User_String FROM Membership INNER JOIN Users ON Users.User_ID = Membership.User_ID INNER JOIN Permission_Levels ON Permission_Levels.PID = Membership.PID WHERE GID = @GID">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Group" DefaultValue="-1" Name="GID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
        Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="User_PL_Source" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:app_migrationConnectionString  %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Permission_Levels"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

...

```
  <td>
    <div class="e_Title">
      Edit Group Permission:</div>
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="User_Repeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="User_Repeater_Source">
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="e_Repeater">
          <tr>
            <th>
              User:
            </th>
            <th>
              Permission Level:
            </th>
            <th>
              Remove User:
            </th>
          </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href='<%#"mailto:" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>'>
              <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "User_String" %></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="User_PL" runat="server" DataSourceID="User_PL_Source" DataTextField="Name"
              DataValueField="PID" AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Submit_User_Remove" runat="server" Text="Remove Permission" OnCommand="Remove_User_Permission"
              CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AID")%>' />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </td>
```

I am looking to pass the PID into the Dropdownlist and make that the selected choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I believe you did not intend to label this asp-classic, but rather asp.net.  No big deal with that.

I would recommend using `OnItemDataBound`.  Something like this to get you started:

```
protected void User_Repeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)e.Item;
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        DropDownList User_PL = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("User_PL");
        ... Set your value here -- consider adding a hidden element with the value you're trying to set it to and get the value the same was as we got the DropDownList
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I believe you can bind to the control itself using markup:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Eval("PID") %>'
```

Good luck.

Comment: Will this work?
If I'm using OnSelectedIndexChanged, wont the changing of the dropdown run the IndexChange command?

Comment: My suggestion would be to give it a try?  Alternatively, I believe you can just bind to the control itself in the markup -- see edits -- I just prefer the flexibility that OnItemDataBound gives you.  Good luck.

Comment: This seems to be working, as my page isn't refreshing nonstop

Good on ya